# Sleep inside closure - Java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, closures, java-8

I know that this question sounds silly - I think that lambdas are execute in parallel, so when I run something like

```
List<Integer> list = ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.forEach(n -> System.out.println(""+n));
```

I woud not get "3\n2\n1\n" every time. I tried to make some kind of sleep() inside the closure, but it looks like that sleep the thread above, not each lambda execution. (Something like n ->  { sleep(n*1000); System.out.println(""+n)}) Can this be done anyhow? Or am I wrong because some parallel stream, etc., should be used instead ordinaly not concurent list? Or is my idea totaly wrong?

Comment: `Thread.sleep` can't make any other thread but the current one sleep. The current thread is the one on which the lambda is executing.

Comment: If you want to testride parallelism, you'll need a bit more than three list elements. Create a few thousand, then see what goes on.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, and what is not happening as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` applied to an Iterable is generally executed sequentially. If you want parallel execution you need to create a parallel stream: `list.parallelStream().forEach(...)`.